# Sorting a sub-array of string[] inside an object[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have the following class:

```
private class st_flow {
    public string[] title;
    public object[] details;               

    public st_flow() {
        title= new string[0]; details = new object[0];
    }
}
```

my `st_flow.details` holds an array of strings, I dont know the size of the arrays, it can be anywhere from `string[5]` to `string[15]` my problem is that I want to sort these arrays. In some cases I want to sort on `st_flow.details[0].mystring[6]` and in other cases on a different index.

**edit**: I'll try to explain and answer to everyone comment; my `st_flow.details` is an object because must be able to hold arrays of any type, each time it holds many arrays of type string, or int etc, but never combined types. so in my code I have something like this:

```
st_flow flow = new st_flow();
string[] content = new string[15];
flow.details = new object[15];
//...
// here I fill my content and each time add it to flow
// this part is inside a loop that each time reset the 
// content and add it to flow incrementing the index
//...
flow.details[index] = content;
```

at this point, out of the procedure we will have `flow.details` that hosts an unspecified number of arrays each of them with an unknow size. We don't actually care of the size of either one. Imagine:

```
// this contains a content[15] string array which [4] value is 50
flow.details[0]; 
// this also contains a content[15] string arraym with [4] value 80
flow.details[1]; 
// i need to sort on this element and be able to do it both DESC or ASC
```

I need to sort my `flow.details` depending on the value (column) of (for example) `content[4]` regardless of it being string or int and regardless of the array size. Hope this clarify my issue, thanks.

Comment: But.... you cannot order a single element., what collection you want to order and based on what?

Comment: `In some cases I want to sort on st_flow.details[0].mystring[6]` - this doesnt make much sense. `details[0]` is just an `object`, it wont have a property `mystring`. And even if it did how do we "sort" on that?

Comment: `public stats() {` look like a constructor, but we are in class `st_flow`: a typo?

Comment: Why is `details` and `object[]`? Store it as the real type which has a property `mystring` and please follow .NET naming and [capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If `st_flow.details` holds an array of strings, shouldn't it be of type `string[]` instead of `object[]`? Oh, and if `x` is some array type such as `string[]`, you can find its length through `x.Length`.

Comment: You need to be more detailed in this question. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @MatthewWatson please see my possible solution below, as it can work but not as supposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have resolved this way, still testing if it works on all cases:

```
        public class flow_dt : DataTable { 
            public flow_dt(string[] columns) {
                this.Clear();
                foreach (string s in columns) {
                    this.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
                }
            }            
        }
```

this way i have the title and the data in one single element and no more array, I can sort and even filter it more easily, as said im still testing it

**edit**: in this case i'm unable to sort it like this:

```
            DataView dv = flow.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = "total DESC";
            flow = (flow_dt)dv.ToTable();
```

I get an error because cannot perform the cast, and I don't understand why since my class inherit from DataTable type.

**edit 2**: and this is the solution for the sorting part: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/insights/890896-how-add-sortable-functionallity-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your *edited case*, just test as being `String[]` and sort:

```
  Object[] details = new Object[] {
    123, 
    new String[] {"x", "a", "y"},       // This String[] array
    "bla-bla-bla",
    new String[] {"e", "f", "d", "a"},  // and this one will be sorted
  };
```

...

```
  foreach (var item in details) {
    String[] array = item as String[];

    if (null != array)  
      Array.Sort(array);
  }
```

...

```
 // Test: print out sorted String[] within details
 Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, details
    .OfType<String[]>()
    .Select(item => String.Join(", ", item))));
```

The test output is (two string arrays are found and sorted)

```
  a, x, y
  a, d, e, f
```

Comment: cause I can host arrays of any type this way, please read my edit, thanks.

Comment: yes and please see if my solution can work and resolve the issue of having a class instead of standard object.